# DDD => behaviour in root aggregate : instanciate other root aggregate

Tags: domain-driven-design, aggregateroot

I have 2 root aggregate : 
- invoice
- complaint

And I have a rule who say : "I can't delete an invoice if a complaint is opened on it".

On my delete behaviour on invoice aggregate I want to check if a complaint exist like :

```
Complaint complaint = ComplaintRepository.findByInvoiceId(invoiceId);

if(complaint.isOpened) {
throw new Exception("Open Complain...");
}
else{
...
}
```

My collegues and I are disagree on this.
They said to me that I can't instanciate a Complaint in my behaviour since Complaint is not in my Aggregate.
My opinion is that I can't have a Complaint attribute in Invoice Class, but :
- I can refered one with a Value Object (they are ok with this)
- I can read/load an instance since I did not call behaviour on it...

Do you have an opinion on this ?

Comment: What kind of data store do you use? If an RDBMS, is there referential integrity between Complaint and Invoice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically you can do what you're proposing: from a certain point of view, if you're injecting a ComplaintRepository interface into the invoice, either through constructor injection or method injection, you're making the Invoice dependant on the contracts of both the Repository and and the Complaint and that's pretty much allowed.

You are right when you say you can't hold a reference to the complaint, but you can inject DDD artifacts (such as factories/repositories/entities) into operations when they're needed to run.

However the main point you must ask yourself is: do you really want this level of coupling between two distinct aggregates? At this point, they're so coupled together they mostly can't operate without one and the other.

Considering all of this, you might be into the scenario where the complaint might just be a part of the invoice aggregate (although your invoice aggregate probably has other responsibilities and you will start to struggle with the "Design Small Aggregates" goal). If you think about it, that's what the invariant "I can't delete an invoice if a complaint is opened on it" is proposing.

If for all means it's not practical for you to model the complaint as part of the invoice aggregate, you have some other options:

- Make these aggregates eventually consistent: instead of trying to delete the invoice in "one shot", mark it as flagged for deletion in one operation. This operation triggers some sort of Domain Event in you messaging mechanism. This event "InvoiceFlaggedForDeletion" will then check for complaints on the Invoice. If you have no complaints, you delete it. If you have complaints, you rollback the Deletion Flag.
- Put the deletion process in a Domain Service. That way, the Domain Service will coordinate the efforts of checking for complaints and deleting the invoice when appropriate. The downside of this approach is that your Invoice entity will be less explicit about it's rules, but DDD-wise this sometimes is an acceptable approach.

Comment: >You are right when you say you can't hold a reference to the complaint<
this is not correct. Evans clearly state that one aggregate root can reference other aggregate roots. you may not however have a reference to a child entity of another aggregate root.

It's in the book...

Comment: Not quite sure I would answer in this way. IMHO, the command handler should be validating the existence of a complaint for that order before it triggers a "delete" for that order.

Comment: having the command validate the other aggregate before the delete would be equivalent to a Domain Service scenario, where you would be trying to synchronize two distinct aggregates that can evolve in independent ways. For instance, between "checking if the order has complaints" and "triggering the order deletion" a complaint can be inserted from another part of your system. No matter how small you make this window, this will be a risk and that's why you should try to avoid multi-aggregate operations.

Answer (score 1):

This statement:

> I have 2 root aggregate : - invoice - complaint`

and this

> And I have a rule who say : "I can't delete an invoice if a complaint is opened on it"`

are mutually exclusive, if you follow the rule of not having a database transaction bigger than one Aggregate  (and you should try to follow it, it's a good rule).

Aggregates are the transactional boundary, this means that what happens inside an Aggregate is strongly consistent with what it will happen in the same Aggregate in the future (the invariants will hold no matter what, the Aggregates are always in a valid state).

However, what happens between different Aggregate instances is eventually consistent, this means that nothing can prevent the system (of multiple Aggregates) to enter in an invalid state without a higher level coordination. Aggregates are responsible only for they data they own.

Code like yours:

```
Complaint complaint = ComplaintRepository.findByInvoiceId(invoiceId);
//    
// at this time a new complain could be added!!!
//
if(complaint.isOpened) {
    throw new Exception("Open Complain...");
}
else{
   invoiceRepository.delete(invoiceId);// and this would delete the invoice although there is a complain on this invoice!!!
}
```

would fail to respect the business rule `I can't delete an invoice if a complaint is opened on it`, unless it is wrapped in a bigger-than-a-single-Aggregate transaction.

Having that said, you have two DDD-ish options:

1. Review your design: merge the two Aggregates into one, for example, make the Compliant a nested entity inside the Invoice.
2. Use a higher level coordinator that would model the "deletion" of an Invoice as a long running business process. For this you can use a Saga/Process manager. The "simplest" such a Saga would also delete the Complains that were added after the Invoice was deleted. A more complex Saga could even prevent the Complain to be added after the Invoice was deleted (for this it would need to somehow intercept the opening of a Complain).

Comment: Probably a command handler could be sufficient, but yes - a saga could also be a viable option.

Comment: @AlessandroSantini no, it shouldn't. You should not put domain logic inside Application layer (considering that your notion of "command handler" is implemented in Application layer).

Answer (score 1):

Aggregate roots should not hold references to repository. This approach has number of issues. Instead, load all objects from repository in application service (command handler) and pass to domain for manipulation. If manipulation engulfs multiple aggregates, either the domain logic is wrong (missing concept) or you might need a domain service. Either way, aggregates are best kept out of asking repository anything.

Answer (score 0):

Another consideration should be - what does *delete* an invoice mean in this domain?

See - http://udidahan.com/2009/09/01/dont-delete-just-dont/

In this case, if you challenge the domain experts, perhaps the requirement around 'deleting' invoices has just come from them being trained about databases and implicitly converting their real requirement into a solution for you to try and be helpful.

Perhaps what they are really talking about is cancelling an invoice? Or archiving it? Or reversing it?

In any case, all these would allow you to model a state transition on the invoice without having to worry about 'orphan' complaints.

This would then prompt the consideration - what should happen to complaints if an invoice is cancelled?  Should the owner of the complaint be notified? Should the complaint undergo it's own state transition?  This could be triggered by an `InvoiceCancelled` event.

In DDD, whenever you see requirements relating to deletion and concerns around orphan records, it's usually a hint that there is some deeper knowledge crunching to be done to understand the real intent of the domain.